# Prove that the sum of two positive real numbers is equal or greater than the square root of their product.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

Trying to prove this:

$A$ and $B$ are positive real numbers.

$A + B \geq \sqrt{AB}$

This is what I wrote:

Proof by Contradiction

$A + B < \sqrt{AB}$

$(A + B)^2 < AB$

$A^2 + AB + AB + B^2 < AB$

$A^2 + AB + B^2 < 0$

Inconsistent with $A>0$ and $B>0$.

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: That seems fine to me.

Comment: Try not to post questions that can be answered with yes/no. Do you have doubts about a specific part?

Comment: Your proof looks good.  This is kind of a special case of the AM/GM inequality.  $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n}}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_{n}}$ with $n=2$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1689293/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

You could have proceeded directly, obtaining
$$
A^2+AB+B^2\geq0
$$
which is true when $A,B>0$.

In fact one even has
$$
\frac{A+B}{2}\geq\sqrt{AB}
$$
and you might want to take a look at the [AM-GM inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html).

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, but contradiction isn't needed:

$AB\leq A^2+2AB+B^2 \implies \sqrt{AB} \leq A+B$.