# Having trouble proving Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I am having trouble proving this inequality: $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$

I can transpose the equation and change around signs. But I am not sure If I need to use k+1 here or just prove the inequality. In discrete math what would my professor be looking for as a proper answer?

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64881/11619) (among others). It generalizes to more than two variables, and goes by the name AM-GM -inequality. The acronym comes from the fact that the inequality states that the *arithmetic mean* of a finite collection of positive numbers is $\ge$ than their *geometric mean*. If you find a better duplicate target, ping me. Dre_Dre: plug in $x=a^2$, $y=b^2$ to arrive at something that looks even more like your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2\;\;$

Comment: $a^2+b^2−2ab=(a−b)^2$, would that be the same as $a^2+b^2−2ab = 0$?

Comment: @Dre_Dre: That would be true if and only if $a=b$.

Comment: @Dre_Dre: No, it just says that $a^2+b^2-2ab$ is the square of some real number. What do you know about squares?

Comment: I know that some number squared it that number times itself. When you transpose $2ab$ why does the equation = $(a-b)^2$ ? And not = 0 as in normal equation transposition?

Comment: @Dre_Dre: Multiply out $(a-b)^2$ and see what you get. As for squares, are they ever negative?