# Show that $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question:**

> Show that the harmonic mean is less than or equal to the arithmetic mean, and also less than or equal to the geometric mean, with equality if and only if $a=b$ ; ie., show that $$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

**My attempt,**

I've shown the first equality which is $$\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{2ab}{a+b}=(a-b)^2\geq0$$

My first question, should I write $\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}\geq0$ or just leave as $(a-b)^2\geq0$?

For the second,

$$\sqrt{ab}-\frac{2ab}{a+b}=\frac{\sqrt{ab}(a+b)-2ab}{a+b}$$

$$=\frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a} b^{\frac{3}{2}}-2ab}{a+b}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{ab}(a+b-2\sqrt{ab})}{a+b}$$

I stuck at here. Can anyone explain to me how to solve this question Thanks in advance.

**I found other similar questions being asked in this site. But my question includes harmonic  which is not a duplicate.

Comment: I would leave it with the division sign as to show that it doesn't work when $a,b<0$

Comment: This has been answered. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64881/35983

Comment: $a+b-2\sqrt{ab}=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2$.

Comment: But my question includes harmonic mean which I think it's not duplicate.

Comment: @Mathxx For the harmonic mean, just apply the AM-GM inequality to the inverses of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Your first equation is simply wrong: $\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{2ab}{a+b}$ is not equal to $(a-b)^2$. You can't leave it like that.

Comment: That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), 
$$\frac {a+b}2\ge\sqrt{ab}\tag{1}$$
Cross-multiplying,

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{ab}}\ge \frac 2{a+b}\\
\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{ab}\ge \frac 2{a+b}$$
$$\sqrt{ab}\ge \frac {2ab}{a+b}\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1),(2)$ gives

$$\color{red}{\frac {a+b}2\ge \sqrt{ab}\ge \frac {2ab}{a+b}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with the second part:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{ab}(a+b-2\sqrt{ab})}{a+b} \ge 0
$$
because
$$
a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab} \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad {a+b\over2}\ge\sqrt{ab}
$$
(this has been already proved in the first part). Just like with the AM-GM case, we have equality only when $a=b$.