# Prove that $\frac{a+b}{2}≥\sqrt{ab}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

I'm working on a proof of AM-GM inequality, but for now I would like to prove more basic propositions.

> Prove that the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality holds for lists of
>   numbers of length $2$. In other words, prove that for all positive
>   real numbers $a$ and $b$
>   $$\frac{a+b}{2}≥\sqrt{ab}$$

My attempt:

We know that $(a-b)^2 ≥ 0 $

Expanding

$$a^2 - 2ab + b^2 ≥ 0$$

Adding $4ab$ to both sides

$$a^2 + 2ab + b^2 ≥ 4ab \implies $$
$$(a+b)^2 ≥ 4ab \implies $$
$$a+b ≥ 2\sqrt{ab} \implies $$
$$\frac{a+b}{2} ≥ \sqrt{ab}$$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Alternatively, let $b=ak,k>0$ so \begin{align}\frac{a+ak}2\ge\sqrt{a\cdot ak}&\impliedby\frac{1+k}2\ge\sqrt k\\&\impliedby k-2\sqrt k+1=(\sqrt k-1)^2\ge0\end{align} which is true.

Comment: [A much better target](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64881/11619).

Answer (score 1):

This proof is correct, but the usual approach is even simpler: rearrange $\frac12(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I am adding a well known geometric proof of this inequality:

[image]
Combining the cathetus theorem ($s^2=b(a+b)$) and Pythagoras' theorem we get: $GM=\sqrt{b(a+b)-b^2}=\sqrt{ab}$.

And since the diameter $a+b$ of the circle c is twice the radius, we get: $AM=radius=\frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: hardy.nice. Sometimes called altitude theorem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem

Answer (score 0):

The OP's proof is perfect. Let's have another.

Let

$$ m\,:=\,\frac{a+b}2 $$
and
$$ d\,:=\,\frac{a-b}2 $$
so that
$$ a\,=\,m+d\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad b\,=\,m-d $$
hence

$$ \sqrt{a\cdot b}\,=\,\sqrt{(m+d)\cdot(m-d)}\,=\,\sqrt{m^2-d^2}
   \,\le\,m\,=\,\frac{a+b}2 $$

***Great!***

> **Remark:** 
>   $$ \frac{a+b}2=\sqrt{a\cdot b}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad d=0 $$
>   i.e.
>   $$ \frac{a+b}2=\sqrt{a\cdot b}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a=b $$