# Show that if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative reals, then $\frac{x + y}{ 2} ≥ \sqrt{xy}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative reals, then

$$\frac{x + y}{2} ≥ \sqrt{xy}$$

Can anybody help me?, I'm not quite sure how to prove this.

Comment: What have you tried ? AM-GM ?

Comment: No need for A.M - G.M. It's a direct one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the AM-GM inequality for 2 numbers $\sqrt{xy}\le\frac{x+y}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64881/proving-the-am-gm-inequality-for-2-numbers-sqrtxy-le-fracxy2)

Answer (score 2):

just note that for $x, y \geqslant 0$:
$$ \left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right)^2 \geqslant 0 \implies x + y -2\sqrt{xy} \geqslant 0 
\implies  \frac{x + y}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{xy} $$

Answer (score 0):

$(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)^2 \ge 0 \iff x-2\sqrt{xy} + y \ge 0 \iff (x+y)/2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$ .

The leftmost inequality is clearly true for $x,y$ non-negative reals.

Comment: maybe there's a sign mistake

Comment: thanks ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Since both $\sqrt{x}\geq0$ and $\sqrt{y}\geq0$, then

$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^{2}\geq0$$

Now expand the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be straightforward from A.M-G.M (as $x, y \geqslant 0$):
$$ \text{A.M} \geqslant \text{G.M} \implies  \frac{x + y}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{xy}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides, so $$\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{4} \ge xy.$$

Multiply by $4$, so $$x^2+2xy+y^2 \ge 4xy.$$

Move terms to one side, so $$x^2-2xy+y^2\ge 0.$$

This factors to $$(x-y)^2\ge 0.$$

Since all real perfect squares are greater than or equal to $0$, the inequality holds.